# Test containment with GoogleTest's Contains matcher?

Tags: c++, googletest, matcher

I'm writing a test and would like to check if some element is contained in a vector. Should be simple and common, so I expected GoogleTest would have some assertion for it. And indeed, it does according to its documentation: http://google.github.io/googletest/reference/matchers.html

In the reference it names a matcher called `Contains(e)` which is supposed to check if a container contains a certain element. Going by the context I'm assuming it would need to be called like this:

```cpp
std::vector<int> vec({1, 2, 3, 4});
EXPECT_THAT(vec, ::testing::Contains(3)); //Should pass the test.
```

However this gives a compilation error:

```
error: no member named 'Contains' in namespace 'testing'
EXPECT_THAT(vec, ::testing::Contains(3));
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

Am I using this wrong? I don't think I've ever worked with these matchers before. However some of the matchers do work correctly, like `::testing::Lt`. Or is the documentation of GoogleTest outdated?

I'm using Clang 12, and GoogleTest 1.11.

As a workaround I'm currently simply using `std::find` and checking for the iterator not being equal to `vec.end()`, but it's not as semantic as I'd like it to be.

Comment: That's strange. You are using it correctly, and function `Contains()` [is there](https://github.com/google/googletest/blame/16f637fbf4ffc3f7a01fa4eceb7906634565242f/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h#L4812) in googlemock header and blame says it wasn't ever changed. Maybe check if you have correct library (and if the file contains this exact function)? Or try with `using ::testing::Contains;` or `using namespace testing;` (although I can't see how it could help).

Comment: It works in an online compiler - https://godbolt.org/z/Y1n678PT9, so the issue is likely with your environment.

Comment: It does require `#include <gmock/gmock.h>`, despite not really being related to the mock class functionality.

Comment: @aschepler This was indeed the issue. I had only included gtest. Would you like to post that as a real answer, so that you get some points and we can document this for the future if someone encounters the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution from the comments:

To use matchers one needs to `#include <gmock/gmock.h>`.

### Explanation:

`EXPECT_THAT(value, matcher)` verifies that `value` matches `matcher` (see [here](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/assertions.html#EXPECT_THAT)) so the second argument has to be a matcher.
And those are part of (formerly separate) GMock, hence they are defined in `<gmock/gmock-matchers.h>` and `<gmock/gmock-more-matchers.h>` which are included by `<gmock/gmock.h>`.